# "This sad memory of mine is something I value."

Tags: phrases

Can I start my essay with this sentence below although the memory is not mentioned before? I'm worried because the sentence starts with the word "this." Is the phrase "this memory of mine" the same thing as "my memory"?

> This sad memory of mine is something I value.

Comment: Hi, welcome to ELL! Some pieces of advice for your future questions. 1) You don't have to include a message of gratitude at the end of every question. The SE consensus is to leave out fluff, and ELL practices the same idea. 2) I am glad your formatting is good. Please also try and choose titles that are specific and to-the-point. 3) Please spell words out. Always "because" instead of "bc".

Answer (score 1):

A sentence like that is *dramatic*;  it creates tension because the memory hasn't been mentioned yet. So it creates an expectation in the reader that the tension will be resolved somehow.  I'd be disappointed if I didn't learn what the memory was by the end of the essay, and why it is valued.

"Memory of mine" is a slightly elevated way to say "My memory" The difference is that you can put a determiner, so you can say "a memory of mine" or "the memory of mine"  or "this memory of mine". But you can't say "*this my memory*".

Dramatic writing is often good, but needs to be done carefully. This kind of style is good for the start of an essay (which you want to be dramatic) but bad for a product manual (which needs to be simple, clear and unambiguous)